# <component-scan> in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, component-scan

If I put the component-scan in spring-common.xml and The Spring MVC cannot find the controllers,why?But if I put the component-scan in springMVC-servlet.xml and it works.

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring/spring-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/springMVC-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

springMVC-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>

<!-- 对静态资源文件的访问 -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/static/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/static/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/image/**" location="/static/image/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

spring-common.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wind">
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Your servlet name is "SpringMVC" and thus it looks into SpringMVC-servlet.xml file for servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you keep your spring-common.xml in your project. Your container (Tomcat, Jboss) will identify them if they are accessible to them. Seems that's not accessible to the containers.

It can be done in 2 ways.

1) Include your spring-common,xml to the web.xml's context config location as follows

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/springMVC-servlet.xml</param-value>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-common.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

2) Import the sprin-common.xml from springMVC-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>

<import resource="spring-common.xml"/>
```

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/load-multiple-spring-bean-configuration-file/

Comment: but I include spring-common.xml and springMVC-servlet in my applicationContext.xml. It seems to has something to do with the spring loading order, but I don't know the details.